# SetState button in for loop throws Maximum Depth exception

Tags: javascript, react-native, render

I'm trying to implement a one to five star rating on a React-Native app using a row of five buttons that each set a score value in the component's state to an integer (1, 2, 3, 4 or 5).

Here's the function that renders the row of five buttons:

```
renderRating(){
    return(
        <Row>
            <>{[1,2,3,4,5].map(star => this.renderStar(star))}</>
        </Row>
    )
}
```

And here's how each button is rendered:

```
renderStar(value){
    return( 
      <Col>
        <Button onPress={this.setState({score: value})}>
          <Text>{value}</Text
        </Button>
      </Col>
    )
}
```

When I try to render this, though, I get a "Maximum update depth exceeded" exception. I tried actually writing all Col elements individually, to see if this was an issue with putting a "setState" function inside a for loop, but it's also throwing the exception there. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Change this: `this.setState({score: value})` to `() => this.setState({score: value})`. You need to set handler and not call it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setState function for updating the state repeatedly being called by the render cycle as state updates then re-render occurs and again function called though, you are getting this error.

Have a try by adding arrow function on button press:

```
<Button onPress={() => this.setState({score: value})}>
```

that means whenever you press the button then and then the setState being called.